# Universal abstract elementary classes and closure operators

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

In this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08532) Hyttinen and Kangas claim that universal abstract elementary classes which are categorical are essentially classes of vector spaces as soon as the model reaches a critical cardinality.

The proof is grounded on the fact that they can equip the class with a closure operator which is Urbanik. I am not practical with the subject, thus I cannot be more precise.

Here comes my question. A universal abstract elementary class comes with a natural closure operator $$\text{cl}(A) = \text{smallest substructure cointaing A} $$

> - How similar or different are these two notions?
> - Is there any intuition behind the one suggested in the paper?

Comment: Well, vector spaces *or trivial pregeometries*. Despite the name, trivial pregometries are not always so trivial. You should probably add the definition of the closure operator defined by Hyttinen and Kangas, since it's buried deep in a rather technical-looking paper. I quickly scanned it, and it looks like it *is* just the "substructure generated by" closure operator, but restricted to the realizations of a minimal type. The point here being that "substructure generated by" won't satisfy exchange in general, so you have to restrict to a piece of the model on which it does.

Comment: This is the same idea as in Morley's theorem - $\text{acl}$ doesn't satisfy exchange in general, but it does when restricted to a strongly minimal set.

Comment: What do you mean when you say acl?

Comment: I mean model theoretic algebraic closure in the context of Morley's theorem: a complete first-order theory. I didn't mean to suggest that acl makes sense in an AEC.